# How to handle line breaks in a templated file included in a Jinja2 JSON template

Tags: python, shell, jinja2, directed-acyclic-graphs, templating

I am writing a Jinja2 template to output a JSON DAG where one value is a string containing a list of commands from an external shell script, (containing templated variables. This works if the commands in the script are semicolon-separated on a single line:

```
echo 'hello'; echo 'world';
```

But, it fails to render the template when formatted with each command on its own line:

```
echo 'hello';
echo 'world';
```

JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 2 column 29 (char 30)` where character 30 is the line break.

I understand this is because JSON does not support multi-line strings. I am using Jinja2's `{% include path %}` to load the file but am not sure how to escape the new lines before rendering them.
I was not able to pipe the `include` output through a Python replace successfully:
`{% include path | replace("\n", " ") %}`

I also tried putting the `include` in a macro with the `replace` calling inside or outside the macro.

Here is a full example of the template and rendering code.

`multi_line.sh`

```
echo 'hello';
echo '{{variable}}';
```

`variables.json`

```
{
    "variable": "world!"
}
```

`template.j2`

```
{
   {# Render included file into single line #}
   "multi": "{% include './multi_line.sh' %}"
}
```

`template_renderer.py`

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import json

with open("./variables.json") as variables_file:
    variables_json = json.load(variables_file)

loader = FileSystemLoader("./")
env = Environment(loader=loader)
template = env.get_template("./template.j2")
rendered_template = template.render(variables_json)
json_output = json.loads(rendered_template)

print(json.dumps(json_output, indent=2))
```

Comment: usually you want to represent line breaks in a json field as `\n`, something else using this string can understand it and display it accordingly.

Comment: json.dumps should be smart enough to escape new lines, so perhaps use json.dumps on the multiline string.

Comment: Could you tell us your os- dependent version of line breaks and on which os you are executing your .py script?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter whether the commands are separated by `\n` or ` ` as both will execute them. Even if `json.dumps` could handle this, it doesn't get that far as template rendering fails. This is when running on `macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit` or `Linux-5.4.188+-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic` (Google Colab notebook). I think I have a solution now utilising a [block assignment](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#block-assignments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to wrap the `include` in a [block assignment](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#block-assignments) and then pipe the results into `replace` to remove occurrences of `\n`.

```
    {% set multi_line_script %}
    {% include 'multi_line.sh' %}
    {% endset %}
    
    {
        "multi": "{{ multi_line_script | replace("\n", " ") }}"
    }
```